# Product of elements of a row is equal to product of one element of a column in squares of a $9 \times 9$ array.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Numbers from $1$ to $81$ are placed in squares of a $9 \times 9$ array.

Then we construct two sets:

$A$ be the set of product of elements of the rows.

$B$ be the set of product of elements of the columns.

Is it possible that two elements of $A$ and $B$ are same?

---

Observations: There are $22$ primes less than $81$.

Also note that of product of all elements of one row is equal to product of all elements of one column, then their prime factorization must me same.

Next, we can't have primes in that row except at the intersection point.

---

I am stuck here. Any hints or help will be helpful.

Comment: There's a relatively minor mismatch between your title and your question text. I believe the title's "... product of *one element* of a column ..." should be "... product of *elements* of a column ..." instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible for an element of $A$ to equal an element of $B$ (i.e., $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$). One example is using a first row of $1$, $80$, $2$, $78$, $3$, $76$, $6$, $56$ and $8$, with the first column being $1$, $40$, $4$, $26$, $9$, $38$, $12$, $28$ and $16$ (each values' product is $7$,$648$,$542$,$720$). This works because, starting after the first value, the product of each pair of values in the row equals the corresponding one in the column, i.e., $80\times 2 = 40\times 4$, $78\times 3 = 26\times 9$, $76 \times 6 = 38 \times 12$ and $56 \times 8 = 28 \times 16$.